# Script to retrieve status of a cron service and display status onto webpage

Tags: php, html, variables, web, ssh

I have the following cron service running on various PI's to display videos on loop:

```
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/surround.sh)
 Active: active (running) since Tue 2018-02-27 11:49:32 IST; 1 weeks 0 days ago
Process: 432 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/surround.sh start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

 CGroup: /system.slice/surround.service
       442 python /usr/sbin//surround -f
       14588 player.bin /var/lib/Videos/test_vid1.h264 /var/lib/Videos/test_vid1.h264 /var/lib/Videos/test_vid1.h264...
```

From my CMS server how can I implement a bash script that connects to each PI over SSH and retrieves the status of the surround service and then displays the status onto a web page. So if the service is currently running, I'd like the webpage to show 'Active' next to each PI's name.

The schedule for the video is stored as a .json file:

```
{"config": {}, "schedule": [{"start": "2017-06-15", "end": "2017-12-15","order": 1, "filename": "test_vid1.h264"}, {"start": "2017-06-15", "end":"2017-12-15", "order": 2, "filename": "test_vid1.h264"}, // and so on..
```

If anyone can find an easier way to achieve this by using a different tool, e.g. PHP, JavaScript etc. I can work around.

**UPDATE**

Based on the feedback I have put together a PHP script:

```
<?php //dashboard.php
$command = "ssh -p 97 -i PI12.rsa pi@192.xxx.xx.xx tail -5 /var/log/vidlog.csv ; sudo service surround status ;
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo "<pre>$output</pre> ";
?>
```

My question is, how can I improve my script further? Specifically I'd like to focus on the following two points:

1. How to incorporate exception handling so the user sees an error message on the web page if something goes wrong.
2. I intend to use this script to connect with multiple PIs - so how can I reuse variables to improve code quality?

Comment: You can use PHP to `"retrieves the status of the surround service"`, format the output like you want and build a web page with the information.    Have fun!

Comment: Hi, that's the bit I'm stuck on the most as I can't figure out how to retrieve the relevant info from the PI. I think once I have a way of retrieving the info from the PI and have it saved it somewhere on my server, I should then be able to set up my web page. Can you recommend links or anything that may help me find a solution?

Comment: You mention that you connect via SSH to your PI and retrieve the status.  Is that through a command line?  Is there a web tool?  I have no way of knowing how your PI application displays it`s status.

Comment: Yes the retrieval of the status is done through the command line. I have a daemon script inside /etc/init.d/ directory for handling `start | stop | restart` commands.

Comment: Based on your feedback, I've produced a PHP script that retrieves the status and the log file from a PI. Could you kindly give me feedback on ways I can improve my script, as I'm sure you can see there are many loopholes in the script - e.g. I have not included exception handling, and since the script will be used to connect to various PIs - how can I reuse my variables?